# JOIN three Wordpress tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress, one-to-many

I need to query a Wordpress database.

The first table is `wp_posts`: from this table I need to retrieve the `ID` and the `post_content` where the `post_title` is `“A”`, `“B”` or `“C”`. This is of course fairly easy.

```
SELECT ID,post_content FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE post_title IN ("A","B","C") and post_type = "plugin_is_writing_this_record"
```

`post_type` is necessary because only a particular Wordpress plugin writes records using that `post_type`.

Problem is that the same plugin (a plugin used to send forms) “deletes” a vital information for me: the `post_author`, that in `wp_posts` is generally **the id of the user who created the post**, **is not the id of the user who posted the form**, but the id of the user who created the post where the form is located. **I need to retrieve the id of the user who posted the form**.

Using the `ID` of the post in `wp_posts`, I could get the email of the user from the table `wp_postmeta`.

If you query this last table this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id = 277125 (*)
```

you get data this way (I cut down data a little):

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key            | meta_value
----------------------------------------------------------
3       | 277125  | _from_email         | from@mail.com
4       | 277125  | _field_your-surname | Surname
5       | 277125  | other_meta_key      | otherdata
6       | 277125  | ...                 | ...
```

At this point, I know `_from_email` meta value is related to the mail of the user who posted the form (I need to retrieve even other meta_keys from this table but this one is functional to the query and to this question).

The table that contains the `ID` I need and the `email` of the user is `wp_users`, a third table.

Is it possible in a single query over the three tables at once to retrieve the data I need? I tried some JOINS but I couldn't get them working properly. Any help is appreciated.

(*) This is a sample query, I need ANY post_id, not only one

Answer (score 0):

please try the query,

```
SELECT wp.ID,wp.post_content, wpm.*
FROM wp_posts wp
RIGHT JOIN wp_postmeta wpm ON wp.ID = wpm.post_id
WHERE 
wp.post_title IN ("A","B","C") 
AND wp.post_type = "plugin_is_writing_this_record";
```

Comment: Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_posts wp (I've got dozens of similar errors, before posting)

Comment: please check again, there was syntax error using from two time, now its fine

Comment: I did it before your comment: but, even if it works, I don't get the data the way I want (eg, there's no mention of the wp_users table)